# Rsync outcome when using both --archive (-a) and --dirs (-d) options?

Tags: rsync

I was looking at a deploy script used by a client of mine that does the following:

```
rsync -ad source destination\
```

Am I correct that if both -a and -d are both specified that because -a implies -r which takes precedent over -d then -d has no effect?

From my reading of the man pages this seems to be the case but searching for a definitive answer has not satisfied me.

I hope Stackoverflow can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the mentioned `rsync` manual, it is the case of `-d` having no effect.

> If you specify both --dirs and --recursive, --recursive takes
>   precedence.

I would remove that `-d` option fom the deploy script. It is only causing confusion.

You could perform a single `--dry-run` just to clear your conscience. :P

Comment: I found some time to do some trial and error testing of this myself just to make sure and indeed -d has not effect that I could discern